# WSL wget command returns HTML rather than downloadable csv file

Tags: windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wget, file-download

I am running WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) and using Ubuntu 22.04 to test my homegrown bash scripts as a part of my CS course.

The task is to download a CSV (comma separated values) file from the link that is provide as part of the course through a Moodle website using either curl or wget.

I have tried running the wget and curl command both in scripts and directly in the terminal but every time I attempt to retrieve the CSV file, I end up getting a HTML file instead.

When the link is clicked, it downloads the correct CSV file, and I don't think anyone one else is having an issue retrieving the file using the wget command.

I also tried to click the link to download, then retrieved the URL from the downloads page in my Edge browser but end up with the same result.

Command run:`wget -O <file-name> <"URL">`

Link provided: https://my.uopeople.edu/pluginfile.php/1808571/mod_book/chapter/471052/Sample-Spreadsheet-1000-rows.csv

Link from downloads page: https://my.uopeople.edu/pluginfile.php/1808573/mod_workshop/instructauthors/Sample-Spreadsheet-1000-rows.csv

Does anyone know if I am missing an argument for the wget command or if this could be an issue with running the wget command in WSL or even an issue of trying to download a plugin.php file?

Comment: That page requires you to authenticate as a user. So you can’t simply use wget without doing that. You’re missing several arguments and commands. When you open the page in a browser, I am making that assumption, your already logged in as an authenticated user.

Comment: I also need to point out to the OP that WSL has nothing to do with this.